# how do you put a close x on the pop up div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a popup window when clicked on a link and need to be able to close the pop up with an x on right corner of the pop up window.

this is my HTML:

```
<div id="popup_box">    <!-- PopupBox DIV-->
    <a id="popupBoxClose">Close</a>    
</div>
```

this the CSS:

```
#popup_box { 
    display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
    position:fixed;  
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
    height:600px;  
    width:850px;  
    left: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 150px;
    z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
    margin-left: 15px;  

    /* additional features, can be omitted */

    padding:15px;  
    font-size:15px;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
}
#popupBoxClose {
    font-size:20px;  
    line-height:15px;  
    right:5px;  
    top:5px;  
    position:absolute;  
    color:#6fa5e2;  
    font-weight:500;
```

this is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {

        loadPopupBox();

        $('#popupBoxClose').click( function() {            
            unloadPopupBox();
        });

        $('#container').click( function() {
            unloadPopupBox();
        });

        function unloadPopupBox() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style        
                "opacity": "1"  
            }); 
        }    

        function loadPopupBox() {    // To Load the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                "opacity": "0.3"  
            });         
        }
```

This is how I call this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">by server chart</a>
```

popupclosebox is disapearing from the div, it is fading out before I do antying. Is it possible to postion popupclosebox little outside the div so that I can see it?

Comment: Any reason to not use excellent existing plugin like http://fancybox.net ?

Comment: Perhaps try looking at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#popupBoxClose, #container").on("click", function(){
    $("#popup_box").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: when I load the page, I dont see the popupBoxclose.

Comment: @user1471980 Sorry, not sure I understand. Here is a fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/HkLDm/2/

Comment: if I put something in that div, I see the close text fade out, not sure what is going on.

Comment: @user1471980 Here is the fiddle updated with text inside the popup <div>, http://jsfiddle.net/HkLDm/3/

Answer (score 1):

You used .fadeIn which will display any DIV with it's standard CSS. If you want to use the integrated dialog (with the X button) you should use .dialog. Here is the reference link:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/